# How to sort and subtract the values in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, analytics

The table contains the following columns.

| Region | Part | Date | Stock | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UP1 | AAA | 20/05/2022 | 20 | 5 |
| UP1 | AAA | 03/05/2022 | 20 | 8 |
| UP1 | AAA | 29/04/2022 | 20 | 5 |
| UP1 | AAA | 13/04/2022 | 20 | 5 |
| UP2 | BBB | 20/05/2022 | 30 | 15 |
| UP2 | BBB | 03/05/2022 | 30 | 10 |
| UP2 | BBB | 29/04/2022 | 30 | 20 |
| UP2 | AAA | 13/04/2022 | 1 | 5 |

I'm trying to match the quantity and stock by excluding the excess quantity for a Region and Part.

In order to get that I've mentioned in Stock-logic below.

The logic would be for a Region and Part, Date with descending order, the stock should get deducted from the above quantity.

Quantity1 is my requirement.

| Region | Part | Date | Stock | Quantity | Stock-logic | Quantity1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UP1 | AAA | 20/05/2022 | 20 | 5 | 20 | 5 |
| UP1 | AAA | 03/05/2022 | 20 | 8 | 15 | 8 |
| UP1 | AAA | 29/04/2022 | 20 | 5 | 7 | 5 |
| UP1 | AAA | 13/04/2022 | 20 | 5 | 2 | 2 |
| UP2 | BBB | 20/05/2022 | 30 | 15 | 30 | 15 |
| UP2 | BBB | 03/05/2022 | 30 | 10 | 15 | 10 |
| UP2 | BBB | 29/04/2022 | 30 | 20 | 5 | 5 |
| UP2 | AAA | 13/04/2022 | 1 | 5 | 1 | 1 |

The minimum of Stock-logic and Quantity would be Quantity1.
If the Quantity is greater than stock then stock has to be shown in Quantity1.

**Thanks in Advance!**

Comment: Why Quantity <> Quantity1 in the last row?

Comment: The requirement is to make the sum of quantity and stock equal. So if Stock is less than Quantity, Quantity1 would be stock value

Answer (score 2):

You can use a subquery to generate the sum of `quantity` values upon the `date` for each `region`, `part`, and then you can use it to get `stock_logic` and `quantity1` values like this

```
SELECT 
    region,
    part,
    date,
    stock,
    quantity,
    stock - quantity_sum AS stock_logic,
    LEAST(stock - quantity_sum, quantity) AS quantity1
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *,
        COALESCE((SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM stock ss WHERE ss.region = s.region AND ss.part = s.part AND ss.date > s.date), 0) AS quantity_sum
    FROM stock s    
) s
```

Output

| region | part | date | stock | quantity | stock_logic | quantity1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UP1 | AAA | 2022-05-20 | 20 | 5 | 20 | 5 |
| UP1 | AAA | 2022-05-03 | 20 | 8 | 15 | 8 |
| UP1 | AAA | 2022-04-29 | 20 | 5 | 7 | 5 |
| UP1 | AAA | 2022-04-13 | 20 | 5 | 2 | 2 |
| UP2 | BBB | 2022-05-20 | 30 | 15 | 30 | 15 |
| UP2 | BBB | 2022-05-03 | 30 | 10 | 15 | 10 |
| UP2 | BBB | 2022-04-29 | 30 | 20 | 5 | 5 |
| UP2 | AAA | 2022-04-13 | 1 | 5 | 1 | 1 |

You can check a working demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=89b693ed186b327a21d533958188989f)